# Trouble scaling assets for consistency on iPhone XS and iPhone XS Max

Tags: ios, swift, image, scale, assets

I'm having trouble trying to get assets to scale properly between the iPhone X/XS and iPhone XS Max (also iPhone 8 vs 8 Plus). I would like the asset to scale proportionally across the different screen sizes.

My understanding is that both the X/XS and XS Max use `3x` assets, but differ in display resolution: `375pt` for X/XS and `414pt` for XS Max. I have designed the asset on Sketch with `375pt` width to scale properly for `3x` on the iPhone X/XS. The asset displays properly on X/XS but stays the same size on the XS Max instead of upscaling to look proportional on the larger display.

I have also tried to resize the asset to `414pt` width, but that creates the opposite result: looks right on the XS Max but too big on the X/XS instead of downscaling to look proportional.

This is what I expect from both screen sizes:
asset scaled correctly:
[image]
But this is what I see on XS Max (Plus):[image]

Ignoring the image heights, see how the XS Max asset stays the same size instead of upscaling proportionally?

It seems like I can force the assets to scale properly on the XS Max by code, by going through every asset and manually scaling them, but I assume that it should be automatic and I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: First, re-post your images with contrasting colors... black on dark-gray is very difficult to see. Second, it's not clear what you are actually doing. Do you have a bezier path? A .png?

Comment: It's a .png asset `@3x` , the example above is a line break image between two sections but it's the same case for all other assets.

I figured out an alternate solution where I can just upload a different `@3x` asset for just the Plus/Max devices and that seems to work. Was wondering why it wouldn't just upscale/downscale automatically.

Comment: What is the `Content Mode` on your image view? Is it set to `Scale to Fill`?

Comment: No it's not set to `Scale to Fill`. I figured since both the X/XS and Max take `@3x` assets that images would scale but they stay the same. I would either have to set the `Content Mode` to `Scale to Fill` which is not really recommended (lower res assets on Max) or just load a second set of resized assets for the Max which I opted for.

Comment: If your image view is not set to scale the image, you can't expect it to, well... scale the image. For a simple wavy line image like that, scaling should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the best solution but I've opted to load a second set of resized `@3x` assets for the Plus/Max devices to look scaled properly across all device screens. This has the added benefit of not upscaling so all assets look sharp, and is a bit more efficient than going through every asset and scaling to fit. However this meant that I had to re-export affected assets designed for `414pt` screens.